# FileNamePattern in RollingFileAppender - logback Configuration

Tags: logback, rollingfileappender

I have the following RollingFileappender in my logback configuration file.

```
<appender name="RollingFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <File>C:\Files\MyLogFile.log</File>      
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
  <FileNamePattern>C:\Files\MyLogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>       
  <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>     
  </rollingPolicy>      
  <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{60} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder> 
  </appender>
```

It does write a file to the above directory as MyLogFile.log but does not append the date as specified in the `FileNamePattern`. Any ideas how can I manage to append the date in my fileName. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good question and confused me too. LogBack keeps logging to the MyLogFile.log and never ends up in the MyLogFile.%{yyyy-MM-dd}.log I wonder what the use is for this file property.

Answer (score 29):

The documentation for [`TimeBasedRollingPolicy`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy) states:

> Note that the `file` property in `RollingFileAppender` (the parent of
>   `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`) can be either set or omitted. By setting the
>   file property of the containing `FileAppender`, you can decouple the
>   location of the active log file and the location of the archived log
>   files. The current logs will be always targeted at the file specified
>   by the `file` property. It follows that the name of the currently active
>   log file will not change over time. However, if you choose to omit the
>   `file` property, then the active file will be computed anew for each
>   period based on the value of `fileNamePattern`.

In your case, just omit the `file` property.

Comment: example on webpage
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html
is broken, it uses both file and fileNamePattern

Answer (score 3):

For example you can use the following configuration. It was tested and works :)

```
<!-- FILE APPENDER WITH PRUDENT MODE -->
<!-- IN PRUDENT MODE CANNOT BE SPECIFIED FILE, THIS PARAM IS OBTAINED FROM FILE NAME PATTERN -->
<!-- IN PRUDENT MODE ONLY TIME BASED ROLLING POLICY IS SUPPORTED - BECAUSE WE HAVE A LOG OF MULTIPLE JVM INSTANCES-->
<!-- SEE MORE AT http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudentWithRolling -->
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${logfile.path}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>${HOSTNAME} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```